# Как пишется слово "перес(е/и)кай"?

Tags: глаголы

Как пишется слово "перес(е/и)кай"?

Comment: Это слово в принципе возможно и через И, но о его значении я предлагаю Вам догадаться самому. ;)

Comment: _Артём Луговой: Это слово в принципе возможно и через И..._ === Возможно-то возможно, только в этом случае И будет ударным, и никаких проблем с выбором И/Е не будет.

Comment: Действительно, Слава, подумал, что будет ударным, но не сообразил, что как раз поэтому проблема и отпадёт.

Answer (score 1):

А что оно значит? В какой букве у вас сомнение?
Есть слово "пересекай" - повелительное наклонение от "пересекать".
А вот [тут](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) есть словари, где вы можете найти нужное слово самостоятельно.

Comment: Вот слово «морковь» похода в словарь точно требует, а то, что в Вопросе,— проверочное имеет. Оно на поверхности лежит.